# How to clear textbox value in SharePoint List using JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-list, inputformtextbox

How can I clear value in this text-box with SharePoint List using JS?

I am using Approval process where Approver 1 put remarks in this text-box and then saves item.

So, when Approver 2 opens the same item, remark column must be empty.

[image]

Comment: Is remark Multiline text filed ? if so, then mark "Append Changes to Existing Text " to Yes for Remark field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint OOTB form and your **Remark** field is multiple lines of text:

You can save the existing remarks from all the Approvers and will be able to get the empty text-box when next approver tries to add his/her remarks using cool feature in SharePoint called **Append Changes to Existing Text**.

For using this first you need to enable the versioning on your list/library. check below article for step by step guide on using **Append Changes to Existing Text**:

[How to track comments with “append changes” functionality in SharePoint List](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-track-comments-with-append-changes-functionality-in-sharepoint-list/).

Comment: Hello, have you tried this? do you have any question regarding this?

Comment: Hi Ganesh Sanap,I already using append changes to existing text. But I want previous remark is deleted. How make like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS code demo for your reference:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var fieldName="MultipleText";
    var defaultText = " ";
    $('nobr:contains(' + fieldName + ')').closest('tr').find('input[id$="TextField_spSave"]').val(defaultText);
});
</script>
```